# C++11 Lambda function compilation error

Tags: c++11, lambda, sdl

i am new using c++11 features and also tryng to use SDL_Widget-2 lib for build a simple Gui for my project. But i am getting stuck in the problem :

```
#include "sdl-widgets.h"
class Builder
{
  public:
    Builder():top_win(nullptr)
      ,but(nullptr)
    {
        top_win=new TopWin("Hello",Rect(100,100,120,100),0,0,false,
          []() {
            top_win->clear();
            draw_title_ttf->draw_string(top_win->render,"Hello world!",Point(20,40));
          }
        );
        but=new Button(top_win,0,Rect(5,10,60,0),"catch me",
          [](Button *b) {
            static int dy=60;
            b->hide();
            b->move(0,dy);
            b->hidden=false;
            dy= dy==60 ? -60 : 60;
          });
    }
private:
    TopWin *  top_win;
    Button *but;
};
int main(int,char**) {
     Builder aViewBuilder;
  get_events();
  return 0;
}
```

with the error in the compilation stage:

In lambda function:

```
 error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function 
 error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
```

this error is printed out twice int the console.
I have try :

```
[this](){}

[=](){}
```

and

```
[&](){}
```

with different compile error but a cannot go more further.
Can any see a fix?

Comment: What is `draw_title_ttf`? Where does it come from? Its not declared in the class.

Comment: is a function from sdl-widgets lib that is a wrapper from sdl2 lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to capture with `[this]` or `[&]`. I suspect that the `TopWin` and `Button` constructors take raw function pointers, and need to take `std::function`s instead.

A plain vanilla function pointer is not compatible with capturing lambdas. `std::function` is able to work like a function pointer that also allows safe storage of captured data. (i.e. the captured objects will need to be properly copied or destroyed when the `function` object is itself copied or destroyed)